# Xamarin.Forms scroll of the editor control in TableView Not Working in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tableview

My code like this

```
<TableView HasUnevenRows="True" Intent="Form" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection>
                 <ViewCell>
                      <Editor x:Name="txtAreaFieldData" HeightRequest="100"/>
                 </ViewCell>
            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

Whenever i enter data, it does not scroll up or down.
Please guide me How i can do that?

Comment: You could try refer to:: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/80360/editor-inside-scrollview-not-scrolling

Comment: And you could try using `EntryCell` instead.

Comment: Us per your refer link i'll do but that currently not working @YorkShen-MSFT

Comment: And I am not using **EntryCell**